# JSON value of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to NSString on Fetch Request

Tags: react-native

I'm using RN-Fetch-Blob library to upload some pictures the user picks.
I need to pass a FormData with the data.

This is the way i'm creating the FormData:

```
var images = [];
this.state.images.map((image) => {
   var img = {
      data: image.data,
      name: image.fileName,
      mimeType: image.mimeType
   }

   images.push(img);
});

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', response.data.id);
formData.append('pictures', images);
```

After this, i'm just calling the service:

```
UserServices.uploadPicture(formData, token)
   .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
      console.warn('uploaded', written / total)
   })
   .then((response) => {
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
   })
   .catch((error) => {
      console.warn('Error while uploading');
    });
```

This would be the fetch function:

```
return RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', Constants.baseUrl + '/pic', {
   Authorization : "Bearer " + token,
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}, formData);
```

After this it throws:

```
JSON value '{
    "_parts" =     (
                (
            id,
            33
        ),
                (
            pictures,
                        (
                                {
                    data = "RNFetchBlob-file://file:///Users/marian-mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/706E797B-0F8E-454D-8ADE-64000001E65D/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED3D7309-8364-4659-9E65-EBA77FC60406/tmp/932FD8E1-1D9F-4ABD-93D6-A1441CF0D71C.jpg";
                    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                    name = "IMG_0003.JPG";
                }
            )
        )
    );
}' of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to NSString
```

Any idea of what's going on? I'm quite sure it's the FormData i'm sending.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have a similar error but I am not using the RN-Fetch-Blob library. For me the error is the same except the JSON value it points to is just an empty object `'{}'`.

Comment: Yes, it was due to the structure i was sending to the API. It was incorrect.